too early in the day
a. It is too early in the day to start work.
b. It is early in the day to start work.

c. It is too early to predict the outcome of the election.
d. It is early to predict the outcome of the election.
I think they are all grammatical, but do (b) and (d) really make sense?
I think they mean that it can be done, but it is nonetheless early. The sentences don't have the 'prohibitive' sense (a) and (c) have. They don't imply it shouldn't be done.
e. He is only four. It's early to go to school, but since he is exceptionally bright, I think he should do it.
I think (e) does make sense. Would you agree?
Would you interpret (b) and (d) in the same way?
Many thanks

early in uses like B and D and  E will often be qualified with "rather" or "quite" though early can stand on its own too.  Unqualified early in such contexts can seem rather "deadpan"  or impassive without further elaboration as is done with E.

This is mostly about understanding the meaning of "too." Think about "I'm hot" vs "I'm too hot."

Taking your first pair of examples, B certainly makes sense.  "He was already harvesting the field at 0500.  It is early in the day to start work, but that is the only way to avoid the heat later".  That's very similar to your E.
D is slightly less intuitive but does also work.  "It is early to predict the outcome of the election but we have a way to do it accurately. It is not too early."  The claim makes linguistic sense, but whether it makes political sense is another matter (but that's true right up until the polls close in the general case, as something unpredictable could happen to one of the candidates).
This means that D makes no less sense than your E - beyond questions of language, the parents may not actually have the option to send their child to school early.

In A, 'too early' means 'before the time that social convention allows drinking alcohol to start', in B, 'too early' means 'before the stage in the election when it is possible to predict the outcome'. In either case the action (drinking, predicting) is judged inappropriate, unwanted, pointless, etc.
We can use 'too' as an adverb before adjectives and adverbs:

to say that something is more than is good, necessary, possible, etc.

B and d both make sense (that is, without 'too').
If you do something too early, you do it before you should (for whatever reason). If you just do something early it's OK to do it at that time, but it may be thought unusually or unexpectedly early.
Too (adverb) - Oxford Learner's Dictionaries

Each case is different and must be treated separately:
I. early/ too early to work..
We shall consider this with an example case - if an employer asks his employee to start work at 6.00 AM instead of the normal 9.00 AM (UK work hours 9.00 AM to 5.00 PM).
Employee's reply and implied meaning:

a.  It is too early in the day to start work.
Meaning: "I have some problem starting work at 6:00 AM.".
b. It is  early in the day to start work.
Meaning: "I'll be there at 6:00 AM, no issue.".

II. early/ too early to predict..

c. It is too early to predict the outcome of the election.
Meaning: "too early" stresses the consequences of predicting prematurely..
d. It is early to predict the outcome of the election.
Meaning:  Prediction is done before time may not be  reliable (milder emphasis).

III. Exception : school admission age..

. He is only four. It's early to go to school, but since he is exceptionally bright, I think he should do it.
The distinction between early and too early depends on context and this case is an exception. It cannot be applied as a general rule.

